# setHours() function on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, worker

I have written a node worker that gets instagrams and tweets and puts them into a database. It's on a heroku schedule that first checks to see if the todays date exists in the database, if it does then I overwrite it with the new data to make sure that day has no duplicate entries.

I'm setting the date with:

```
new Date(d).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

When I do this on my local machine I get todays date Nov 11th:

```
todays date 1447228800000
```

When I do this on heroku I get the day before Nov 10th and the hours and minutes are not 0:

```
todays date 1447200000000
```

So when I go to fetch the data for that day and try to display I am getting the day before. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Timezone, needed to update my timezone on heroku. This question is dumb.